# Save video file when the app goes in background [Camera2Api]

Tags: android, video, background, android-camera2, onpause

I have a camera app. My problem is that when i'm recording and the app goes in bacground the file that mediarecorder had is void. I want to save the file is saved first. I have tried the same code that i use when a click the stop button, but it does not work.
Any suggestions?

This is my onPause() method

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (isRecording) {
        stopRecordingVideo();
        Log.d("YUI", "true");
        fileQueue.addToQueue(mCurrentFile);

    } else {
        Log.d("YUI", "false");
        mMediaRecorder = null;
        closeCamera();
    }
    counter--;
    stopBackgroundThread();
    //        if (mCurrentFile != null) {
    //            mCurrentFile.delete(); // delete empty file
    //        }
    super.onPause();
}
```

> ```
> public void stopRecordingVideo() {
>     stopRecordingVideo(false);
> }
> ```

```
private void stopRecordingVideo(boolean kill) {
    // UI
    isRecording = false;

    // Stop Recording
    closeCamera();
    if (!kill) {
        openCamera(mCameraLayout.getWidth(), mCameraLayout.getHeight());
    }
}

private void closeCamera() {
    try {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
        if (mPreviewSession != null) {
            mPreviewSession.close();
            mPreviewSession = null;
        }
        if (mCameraDevice != null) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            mMediaRecorder.release();
            mMediaRecorder = null;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        Crashlytics.log("closeCamera error");
        Crashlytics.logException(ie);
        ie.printStackTrace();
        getCam2Listener().onInterruptedException(ie);
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.");
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Crashlytics.log("closeCamera error");
        Crashlytics.logException(exc);
    }

    finally {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what happens inside `stopRecordingVideo()`

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: looks like it should be `stopRecordingVideo(true)` when called from **onPause()**

Comment: No, that does not solve the problem

Comment: *chat* is not working for some reason. Your question is not very clear. Please provide more info: what happens when you press the 'Stop' button, which file do you see in this case? What is the relation between **mPreviewSession**, **mCameraDevice** and **mMediaRecorder**? Maybe, everything will work as intended if you stop  **mMediaRecorder** before you stop the **mPreviewSession**?